# is there way to plot graph only for constant data out of mixed data in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, sipp

I am using SIPp tool for sip call that gives me a csv stat file (i configured every 5 sec new row is generated) with columns of current calls (integers) like **0,5,12,25,45,60,60,60,59,60,60,45,32,25,15,5,0**.

1. above is with 5 calls per sec with max call limit 60(pls ignore missing values in between). So, this would be my y-axis values.
2. For x-axis (this is my another challenge :( .. )as call duration can be anything like 30 seconds to even 2 hours. csv files gives me timestamp in this format "**2021-12-14  01:11:41.574282 1639424501.574282**". for which (as per my best I converted all these timestamps to a list of successive values' diff i.e. 5 using below:

   ```
    T=[]
    for t in time:
       tvalue= t.split("\t")[2]
       T.append(int(float(tvalue)))
    t_interval = [j-i for i, j in zip(T[:-1], T[1:])]
   ```

t_interval gives me [5, 5, 5, 5, 5...so on]

If I draw a linear graph, that will be a curved one (start with 0 , flat line , ends with 0 ), **I want to draw something like "when first time max call limit reach (i.e. 60) and after my total call duration say 120 seconds (can vary also) when calls start ending i.e last 60  (till this point)"**
note:- in between sometime there may be values like 58/59.
is there a way in metaplot or any python plotting module to do this easily?

with all above said, I am able to plot something that captures all values but not the line (that should be flat for max calls only against time) using below :

```
calls_tup = tuple(zip(list(calls),list(failedcalls)))
x= np.linspace(0,sum(t_interval),len(calls))
y= np.array(calls_tup)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
```

3. Failedcalls is another line to be shown in my graph. that is not an issue. :)

[image: need to have only the flat line from this plot]

Comment: Can you add a sketch of an example to show what you need exactly? Can you also add some minimal code to make it easier to communicate?  `plt.plot` will draw straight lines between successive points.  `plt.step` will draw it as a step function.  If you just want a straight line, you could try `plt.axhline(max(values))`.

Comment: Why did you tag gnuplot? Are you looking for a gnuplot solution? Do you want to plot a line for 60 or in general for the maximum (which in your example is 60)? So, I understand, only if you have your value (60) several times in a direct sequence, you want to plot a line. What if you have 60 only once? Plot a point? What should be the x-values? The index of the number? A sketch corresponding to you example data would be helpful.

Comment: @theozh, my bad I have removed gnuplot tag. I have also tried my best to edit question with more info. I hope it is helpful and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach that searches for positions of the array with equal successive values. Then a horizontal line of length 1 is drawn from that position.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

values = [0, 5, 12, 25, 45, 60, 60, 60, 59, 60, 60, 45, 32, 25, 15, 5, 0]
values = np.array(values)
pos_equal = np.argwhere(values[:-1] == values[1:]).squeeze()
x = np.vstack([pos_equal, pos_equal + 1, np.full_like(pos_equal, np.nan, dtype=float)]).T.ravel()
y = np.repeat(values[pos_equal], 3)
plt.plot(x, y, ls='-', lw=3, color='r')
plt.plot(values, ls=':', lw=0.5, color='b')
plt.show()
```

[image: horizontal lines for equal positions]

The x and y arrays look like:

```py
x: [ 5.,  6., nan,  6.,  7., nan,  9., 10., nan]
y: [ 60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60,  60]
```

The `nan` values provoke an interruption in the lines.

Comment: Yes , I am able to draw like you suggested. I am thinking as I will always know the first and last occurrence of my max_call value (60 in the case), I should strip rest all values and use that list as new values for y-axis input . Though x-axis dynamic scaling is yet something i need to think,. I will run longer duration tests and check if my logic yet works ..Thank you very much JohanC :)